# Leaflet Weighted Heatmap JavaScript

Tags: javascript, leaflet, heatmap

I'm trying to create a heatmap from a data like ;

```
 var ankara_sincan = L.point(32.5850, 39.9719);
    var ankara_dikmen = L.point(32.8406, 39.8964)
    var testData = {
        max: 8,
        data: [{lat: ankara_sincan.x, lng: ankara_sincan.y, weight: 3}, {
            lat: ankara_dikmen.x,
            lng: ankara_dikmen.y,
            weight: 2
```

I'm using heatmap extension for leaflet in [this](https://github.com/pa7/heatmap.js) page .

The problem is ; in document page and in examples a function called **HeatMapOverlay** is used as shown below ;

```
  var heatmapLayer = new HeatMapOverlay(cfg);
```

But in my code I get this error ;

> Uncaught ReferenceError: HeatMapOverlay is not defined

I've defined sources at the beginning of my code like ;

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="boge\leaflet.label.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/leaflet.css" />
<script src="/plugins/leaflet-heatmap.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css" />
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="/build/heatmap.js"></script>
<script src="boge\leaflet-pip.min.js"></script>
<script src="/plugins/leaflet-heatmap.js"></script>
```

I don't understand why compiler couldn't find my **HeatMapOverlay** function in predefined locations. Thanks in advance >_<

Comment: Try this for the plugin:  src="http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.heat/dist/leaflet-heat.js"

Comment: This is totally a wild guess, ok? remove `/plugins` and leave only `<script src="/leaflet-heatmap.js"></script>`... let's see what happens.

Comment: Still doesn't work ! I'm thinking maybe it is because of the compiler I use. I'm using webstrom 2016.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple typo. Replace

```
new HeatMapOverlay(cfg)
```

with

```
new HeatmapOverlay(cfg)
```